# Why does 'pipenv lock -r' errors with 'No such option: -r'?

Tags: python, dockerfile, pipenv

With this minimal *Dockerfile*

```bash
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

RUN pipenv lock -r > requirements.txt
```

The `pipenv` command fails with the error message:

> Usage: pipenv lock [OPTIONS]
> Try 'pipenv lock -h' for help.
>
> Error: No such option: -r

And, so, the docker build fails with

> The command '/bin/sh -c pipenv lock -r > requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 2

My pipenv is in version 2023.2.4.

`pipenv lock -h` doesn't show the option `-r` exists and I can't find anything online for this. Is the option deprecated? Is it changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, this command does not work anymore

```bash
pipenv lock -r > requirements.txt
```

The recommended replacement is

```bash
pipenv requirements > requirements.txt
```

As pointed in [the issue 5253](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/5253) from there issue tracker.